# If background is not transparent in ViM, I see the background color of the terminal, which is different

Tags: colorscheme, color

This problem might be a terminal problem, but maybe some of you managed to solve it.

I've been using ViM with the default colorscheme, which has a transparent background, so I see the background color set for my terminal emulator (I use `st` with the anysize patch by the way).
Now, this morning I wanted to try out some new colorschemes and I noticed that if ViM sets a background color, then it leaves a bit of border of the same color of the terminal emulator.

I'd like to get rid of this effect without having to change the colors of my terminal.

Here's a screenshot of the problem (with the blue colorscheme): notice that the borders have a different background color.

[image: Border problems]

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `:let &t_ut=''` change anything?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Unfortunately it does not work. I tried it by opening a new vim instance in the terminal, changing the colorscheme to blue and then executing the command. Nothing happens. :-(

Comment: note sure, but note, that the default vim colorschemes may not be optimal anymore, so perhaps it is a bug there

Comment: It’s also very possible that vim doesn’t take up the entire terminal width/height (for one reason or another; possibly there is padding so characters aren’t right on the edge) and so vim just doesn’t draw there? @ChristianBrabandt is that plausible?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Not sure if it helps, but it also happens with SpaceViM, which is a sort of a collection of ViM plugins well organized. SpaceViM uses gruvbox as the default colorscheme and I noticed it's not present in ViM. I'm not sure how old is that colorscheme though

Comment: ah, so is this about the black margin? I thought about the blue background color. In that case, I believe @D.BenKnoble might be correct. If the space of your terminal is not sufficient to draw a new column or line, you might encounter such margins. There is nothing that can be done (except perhaps for styling those, see :h gtk-css I believe)